# Query Failed!Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to put this into the database. 
And i am getting an unexpected error, however, saying Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. What is wrong with the query?

```
<?php 
    if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
    $charge   = $_REQUEST['ocharge'];
    $fname    = $_REQUEST['ofname'];
    $lname    = $_REQUEST['olname'];
    $mobile   = $_REQUEST['omobile'];
    $add1     = $_REQUEST['oadd1'];
    $add2     = $_REQUEST['oadd2'];
    $postcode = $_REQUEST['opostcode'];
    $state    = $_REQUEST['ostate'];
    $country  = $_REQUEST['ocountry'];
    $weight   = $_REQUEST['oweight'];
    $credit   = $_REQUEST['ocredit'];
    $pin      = $_REQUEST['opin'];
    $city     = $_REQUEST['ocity'];

        $date=date('Y-m-d');
        $time=time('H:i:s');
        $result=mysql_query("insert into order values ('$date','$time','$charge','$fname','$lname','$mobile','$add1','$add2','$postcode','$state','$country','$weight','$credit','$pin','$city')");
        $orderid=mysql_insert_id();    

        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_price($pid);
            $result1=mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ('$orderid','$pid','$q','$price')");
            if($result1 === FALSE)
            {
                die("Query Failed!".mysql_error().$result1);
            }

        }
        die('Thank You! your order has been placed!');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Exactly what it says: You have not defined the same number of values as there are columns. This is why you should always explicitly define the list of columns for which you are providing values - even if it's all of them, because you never know if you might want to add a column later.

Comment: we need structure of `order_detail` table.

Comment: Has order_detail only 4 fields?You probably have an id field so you can insert a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do something like that:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Which requires for your knowing all columns, and their sequence. You need to use them all.

However, if you know which columns you may omit, you can use this method:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Here, you specify which columns you want to add. If all the rest of columns have defined default values or accept NULL, you will be okay.